# OFDM channel estimation using the transmitted signal multiplied with a matrix

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, ofdm, optimization, channel-estimation

I have OFDM system, where the modulated signal $x$ with length $N$, and $N$ is the number of subcarriers in OFDM symbol. $x$ is multiplied with a well-known unitary matrix $G \in N \times N$ before performing the inverse Fourier transform $F^{-1}$ matrix to produce the time-domain signal $y$, so:

$y  = F^{-1}Gx \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$ ,

The cyclic prefix is added to $y$, and it is transmitted through the channel $h$, the received signal $r$ can be expressed, when ignoring the noise, as

$r = h © y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$ , where $©$ represent the circular convolution.

At the recieving end, when removing the CP and convert the received signal into frequency domain by multiplication with discrete Fourier transform, the resulting signal become

$R = Fr =  HY = HGx \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$ where $H$ is the frequency-domain channel impulse response.

Assuming we transmitted pilot data in $x$, it means a part of signal $x$ is transmitted as pilot which is well known, can we estimate the channel using $R$ ? for example, Is there any optimization algorithm which can estimate $H$ to produce the well-known pilots in $x$, then that $H$ will represent the estimated channel?

**EDIT:**

In short, I need to estimate the channel using pilots data inserted in frequency domain subcarriers in presence of the matrix $G$ used before performing iFFT operation. It means I want to use comb type pilots (It is not block type) where the pilots are inserted in frequency domain in each symbol and other subcarriers will carry data.

Comment: Your question is answered in any decent wireless communications textbook. Could you narrow down your question to the specific aspect of estimation and/or equalization that you're struggling with?

Comment: @MBaz My process is different to the others systems existed in wireless communications textbooks by the matrix $G$, I need to estimate the channel using pilots but the data was multiplied with matrix $G$ before performing the iFFT operation.

Comment: I saw that, so your pilots are actually $Gx$, right? Use $R$ to to estimate $H$, equalize, recover $Gx$, multiply by $G^{-1}$ and obtain $\hat{x}$. Alternatively, you may consider $HG$ to be the channel and estimate it directly. I fail to see the difficulty, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @MBaz I need to use comb type pilot  (not block type). I case of using block type, that becomes straightforward as you mentioned but what I am asking about is when using comb type. Thanks for your clarification; I added that note into the question.

Comment: What's the problem with estimating $HG$ as the "effective" channel?

Comment: @MBaz The problem is that I am considering the channel to be constant only in each symbol, so channel estimation based on block type pilot becomes no practical. It means from each symbol to another, the channel will be variant.